# Is it a good way to remove 1 element from an array without using a temporary array and without declaring an allocatable variable?

Tags: arrays, fortran

I want to know if the following implementation is a good way to remove an element from an array without moving by a temporary array and without considering `array` as an allocatable variable:

```
subroutine delete_elements(array, index,size)
    type(tcb),dimension(size),intent(inout)::array
    integer::size,index,i
    
    do i=index,size-1
       array(i)=array(i+1)
    end do
    size=size-1 
 end subroutine delete_elements
```

I use this subroutine as following:

```
call delete_elements(tasks_ready_master,1,size(tasks_ready_master))
```

My array is called `tasks_ready_master`. I want to retire the first element. `size(tasks_ready_master)` should be the size of the array used. I'm not sure about the last argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems here to address: data structure and change of constant argument.

---

**Data structure**

You are using an operation (`erase`) on a data structure (`array`) which is inherently bad at it.

Why is that?
For removing **one** element you need to move **all** following elements in the array.
[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure#Efficiency) is the wikipedia article talking about comparison of efficiencies of array to other data structures.

---

**Change of constant argument**

In your code is a problem:
you supply the *constant* total size of the array `size(tasks_ready_master)` but within the procedure you actually change that argument `size=size-1`.

A quick fix would look something along the lines of

```
integer :: n
real :: a(5) = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]

n = 5
call erase(2, n, a)  ! result: n = 4, a(1:n) = [1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
call erase(3, n, a)  ! result: n = 3, a(1:n) = [1.0, 3.0, 5.0]
call erase(1, n, a)  ! result: n = 2, a(1:n) = [3.0, 5.0]
```

Here I rewrote your procedure to reflect the arguments intent and using vectorization.

```
subroutine erase(i, n, array)
  !! removes the i-th element within the array.
  !! the array has the total length size(array) but currently only uses n elements.
  integer, intent(in)    :: i
    !! i-th element to erase
  integer, intent(inout) :: n
    !! current length
  real,    intent(inout) :: array

  array(i:n-1) = array(i+1:n)
  n = n-1
end subroutine
```

---

**Mask**

For many operations you can define masks such that you do not need to change the actual array but rather mark the item to delete in another logical array.
You must think of it like turning off specific elements within the array.

There is the downside of the extra memory you need to allocate for the mask but the performance boost from not needing to shift lots of elements outweighs it in most cases.

The following example hopefully explains that in more detail

```
program main
  integer, parameter :: n = 5
  logical :: m(n) = .true.
  real    :: a(n) = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]

  print *, sum(a) ! output: 15

  ! "erase" 2nd element:  a = [1.0, XXX, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
  m(2) = .false.
  print *, sum(a, mask=m) ! output: 13

  ! "erase" 3rd element (wrt original array): a = [1.0, XXX, XXX, 4.0, 5.0]
  m(3) = .false.
  print *, sum(a, mask=m) ! output: 10
end program
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, whenever you will remove an element using your method delete_elements() it will allocate less memory than memory required in creating temporary array.

Comment: What do you mean by "it will allocate less memory"? OP does not allocate any memory within his procedure (other than local variables..)!